# GStreamer decodebin is not selecting my plugin

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have written GStreamer plugin for aac audio parser. Since there is already open source plugin "`aacparse`" available on my device, the decodebin was selecting it over my plugin.

I did `gst-inspect-1.0` of "`aacparse`" and my plugin. I found that sink and source caps are exactly same.
But open source plugin had rank `257 (primary+1)`.

I understand that `decodebin` selects plugin with highest rank. So I increased my plugin's rank to `260 (primary+4)`.

But still the `decodebin` is selecting open source plugin but not mine.

If I delete the open source plugin library, `decodebin` is picking mine and working fine. But I cannot remove the open source library due to some other dependency.

Could you please help me understand what is going wrong here?